# Arraylist doesn't add

Tags: java, xml, parsing, arraylist, addition

I've a problem that I don't understand about adding an element into the ArrayList.
The result show me that it hasnt added the two computers.
Someone can help me ?

```
    Computer computer;
    GenerateXML xml;
    Parser dom = new Parser();
    List computers = new ArrayList();
    computer = new Computer("2", "fisso", "Corsair", "Venom 2X", 1029971511, 4.5f, 12, 32, 600, 24.0f, 1900, "Linux", "21-10-2021");
    computers.add(computer);
    computer = new Computer("3", "laptop", "Microsoft", "Surface", 1000091801, 4.5f, 12, 32, 600, 24.0f, 1900, "Linux", "21-10-2021");
    computers.add(computer);

    try {
        xml = new GenerateXML(computers);
        xml.printToFile("computer.xml");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException exception) {
        System.out.println("Errore generate!");
    }

    try{
        computers = dom.parseDocument("computer.xml");
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException exception){
        System.out.println("Errore parsing!");
    }
    System.out.println("Numero computers: " + computers.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < computers.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(computers.get(i));
```

The result is:

```
Numero computers: 0
```

Comment: The list is overridden here: `computers = dom.parseDocument("computer.xml");`. I suspect that `dom.parseDocument("computer.xml")` produces an empty list.

Comment: Can you verify that the XML files contains something ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to flush the output to the XML file.

Comment: I'm sure arraylist add works.  But the problem might have to do with writing the array list to file and reading the data from the file.  Nothing to do with arraylist add method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize computers to be an empty list.

```
List computers = new ArrayList();
```

Then you add two computers to your list.

```
computer = new Computer("2", "fisso", "Corsair", "Venom 2X", 1029971511, 4.5f, 12, 32, 600, 24.0f, 1900, "Linux", "21-10-2021");
computers.add(computer);
computer = new Computer("3", "laptop", "Microsoft", "Surface", 1000091801, 4.5f, 12, 32, 600, 24.0f, 1900, "Linux", "21-10-2021");
computers.add(computer);
```

At this point, your computers list will contain two computers. The size of the list will be two.

Then you assign a new value to the computers list in your second try/catch block. By doing this, you lose the list you had created and populated before. After this, computers will be a completely new list.

```
computers = dom.parseDocument("computer.xml");
```